# Проблемы со строками в python3 tempfile

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Привет всем!

Просьба помочь разобраться с `tempfile` в `python3.4` под centos6. Допустим, я с помощью `mysql.connector` делаю выборку из таблицы по двум полям и получаю в `cursor` примерно следующее

```
bgp_path 15970839
sys_calls 3189266
regs 2802296
sys_users 2463881
routes 1253487
current 879094
```

Теперь всё, что я хочу - это получить некий временный файлик который бы содержал вот всё прям в таком виде и `some.str` в начале каждой строки

```
some.str bgp_path 15970839
some.str sys_calls 3189266
some.str regs 2802296
some.str sys_users 2463881
some.str routes 1253487
some.str current 879094
```

чтоб потом этот файлик передать системным вызовом через `subprocess` некоему исполняемому файлу как аргумент. Что я для этого делаю:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fp:
    print (fp.name)

    for line in cursor.splitlines():
        if len(line) == 0: continue

        tmp = "some.str {0}".format(line)
        fp.write(tmp.encode('utf-8'))
        fp.seek(0)
    print(fp.read())
```

и получаю в ответ `b'some.str current 879094881'` либо `b''`. Пример https://ideone.com/bumMi3

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: отступы в Питоне имеют значение. Что по вашему `fp.seek(0)` делает?

Comment: `Что я делаю не так?` - очевидно же, каждую строку с начала файла записываете.

Comment: Я не знаю куда впихнуть этот `fp.seek(0)`. Если его не использовать или использовать за циклом - файл будет пустой.

Comment: задайте отдельный вопрос с явным примером где вы пустой файл получаете. Только не нужно тащить с базой данных пример. Искусственные данные пишите: `for line in 'abc':` [mcve]

Comment: @jfs прошу, маэстро https://ideone.com/bumMi3

Comment: информацию (код) в сам вопрос помещать следует. Не хотите отдельный вопрос задавать, ваше дело. Прочтите мой первый комментарий. Подумайте, что изменится, если *отступ* перед fp.seek(0) изменить в примере в вопросе и как это отличается от вашего примера на ideone (порядок строк в Питоне также имеет значение, изменение отступа не меняет порядок строк).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fp.seek(0)` внутри цикла приводит к тому, что каждую новую строку вы выводите с начала файла, каждая новая строка перезаписывает предыдущую.

По поводу того, что строки не записываются в файл. Вывод в файл буферизируется (накапливается в буфере, потом выгружается относительно большим куском при заполнении буфера, закрытии файла, или при операции `seek`, как в вопросе). Чтобы выгрузить данные в файл принудительно, делайте `fp.flush()` после цикла, или создавайте временный файл с отключенным буферизированием: `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(buffering=0)`

Пример:

```
import tempfile

data = '''
bgp_path 15970839
sys_calls 3189266
regs 2802296
sys_users 2463881
routes 1253487
current 879094
'''.lstrip()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fp:
    print (fp.name)

    for line in data.splitlines():
        if len(line) == 0: continue

        tmp = "some.str {0}\n".format(line)
        fp.write(tmp.encode('utf-8'))

    fp.flush()  # в данном случае не обязательно, т.к. seek сам флушит файл
    # Но перед чтением файла сторонней утилитой файл все же нужно будет зафлушить
    fp.seek(0)  # чтобы прочитать содержимое, нужно сначала перейти в начало файла - но только непосредственно перед чтением файла
    print(fp.read())
```

Вывод:

```
C:\Users\3084~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpigel0fsa
b'some.str bgp_path 15970839\nsome.str sys_calls 3189266\nsome.str regs 2802296\nsome.str sys_users 2463881\nsome.str routes 1253487\nsome.str current 879094\n'
```

Если нужно получить результат в виде текстового файла, можно в `NamedTemporaryFile` указать, что файл нужно открыть в текстовом режиме, тогда не нужно будет каждый раз явно перекодировать строки в байты:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+t', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    print (fp.name)

    for line in data.splitlines():
        if len(line) == 0: continue

        tmp = "some.str {0}".format(line)
        print(tmp, file=fp)

    fp.flush()
    fp.seek(0)
    print(fp.read())
```

Результат:

```
C:\Users\3084~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpd4moggw9
some.str bgp_path 15970839
some.str sys_calls 3189266
some.str regs 2802296
some.str sys_users 2463881
some.str routes 1253487
some.str current 879094
```

Comment: Как же всё сложно-то, мне всего лишь надо во временный файл поместить текст :'(
Ни `fp.flush()` ни `buffering=0` не помогают, в файл всё так же записывается `b''`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос как пробовали

Comment: https://ideone.com/bumMi3 в вопрос добавил пример.

Comment: Добавил рабочий пример

Comment: То есть, получается, всю "магию" выполняет `print(line, file=fp)` ?

Comment: Нет, `print(line, file=fp)` в данном случае эквивалентно `fp.write(line + '\n')`. В зависимости от того, какую вы магию имеете в виду - ее делает или `flush`, или режим открытия файла `'w+t'` (t - текстовый режим)

Comment: Если сравнить с вашим примером, то вы флушите файл (если открыть файл извне, то вы увидите, что данные в него записались), но в программе пробуете прочитать что-то его конца (после последней строки). Сравните свой пример с первым примером из ответа.

Comment: Очень интересно и непонятно) Премного благодарен Вам за объяснение! :)

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, уточняйте. По поводу seek еще раз: после записи данных в файл текущая позиция чтения/записи становится в конце файла. Когда вы пробуете оттуда что-то прочитать, то получаете пустую строку (после конца файла ничего нет). Чтобы прочитать весь файл, нужно после записи всех строк переместить позицию чтения/записи в начало файла (с помощью `fp.seek(0)`), а потом уже читать файл.

Comment: Вот теперь понятно, грубо говоря, чтоб увидеть чего там есть, надо было `seek` после цикла использовать. Ну и по поводу заполнения файла тоже понял, мне как раз и надо было `'w+t', encoding='utf-8'`. Очевидно это правильный способ формирования временных файликов, но очень какой-то не очевидный и сложный для меня :)

Comment: @whoknow возможно вы хотите: `with io.StringIO() as buf, redirect_stdout(buf): for row in data: print("format...", *row)` и в конце with-блока: `text = buf.getvalue()` чтобы напечатанное как строку получить, так как на диск нет необходимости писать, чтобы тут же назад прочитать в строку.

Comment: @jfs эмм, наверно я не совсем понял Вашу рекомендацию. Мне нужно сформировать текстовый файл который бы я через subprocess передал как аргумент другому процессу, а по завершении же его - удалить файл. Для этого я выбрал tempfile, так как считаю, что это правильный путь в рамках моей задачи. Предложенный insolor'ом вариант вполне мне подходит. Только бы ещё научиться строку из последней итерации цикла вначало файла помещать не затирая его))

Comment: @whoknow: если ваша задача писать ввод какой-либо команде, которую вы из Питона запускаете, то это отдельная задача с разными решениями. Одно из решений: `with redirect_stdout(process.stdin): ... print('что-угодно')` Большой ли у вас ввод? (проще всего ввод сразу как строку передать) Зависит ли ввод от вывода этой же команды? (неинтерактивный ввод обычно проще--нет проблем с буферизацией). Если по имени требуется передать, то одно из решений это передать временный файл, но это не единственный вариант [Multiple pipes in subprocess](https://goo.gl/bPEZTA) Это лучше отдельным SO вопросом задать.

Comment: @jfs я наверно снова Вас не понимаю, либо не могу донести что-то... есть некий бинарный, исполняемый файл, который аргументом принимает текстовый **файл** (не слово, не строку, а именно текстовый файл) через ключ `--input-file`. Так вот моя задача была в том, чтоб этот файл сформировать путём выборки SQL и её последующего парсинга. В этом файле более 600 строк.

Comment: @whoknow я этот вариант явно упомянул *"если по имени требуется передать"* и даже ссылку на возможные решения fifo, `/dev/fed/#N` привёл. Вот [ещё один пример /dev/fd решения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894258/4279). Если это всё ещё не ясно, то упомяните принимает ли ваша команда специальные имена файлов типа `"-"` (означает данные через stdin подаются), какая OS (Windows, macOS) и опубликуйте как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос.

Comment: @jfs я Вам безмерно благодарен, но у меня нет больше вопросов ни по передаче файла в команду, ни по способам формирования. Вопрос был именно по модулю `tempfile` так как там уже реализован умными программистами цикл жизни файла, как раз какой мне нужен - лишь во время передачи его через `subprocess` далее. Проще говоря, я не стал изобретать велосипед)

Comment: @whoknow временный файл не равнозначен pipe. Ничего страшного если этого не понимаете, если временный файл работает в вашем случае.